# Should we remove humor from answers to popular questions?

Tags: discussion

I came across this question [What causes signal 'SIGILL'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901867/what-causes-signal-sigill) looking for a explanation of the SIGILL exception type.

However, I find that the answer is

> Bury a dead cat at midnight when full moon

And the answer is also having a score of 70 (at the time of writing).

I'm conflicted as if to call a moderator down to <s>delete</s> inflict justice on the answer since a lot of people clearly found it useful. But I really don't feel the answer is appropriate for what is a almost click-bait like title, that shows up in the top of Google's search results.

What can we as a community do to improve the post?

Comment: The answer has been around for years, and people don't seem to mind the one humorous sentence. Why should we do anything about it?

Comment: Because of the very broad title, that affectively make the question a wiki-like answer for anyone searching for SIGILL on the internet

Comment: Then why not just fix the title?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I made the title of *this* question a bit more generic. It originally looked like something that's not on-topic on Meta.SO.

Comment: @Glorfindel Meta.SO though ;-) Definitively would been off topic on Meta.SE.

Comment: @Yannis The answer itself is also very low quality, just suggesting a restart doesn't really help contributing to the original question, and certainly not over the ages.

Answer (score 27):

My biggest issue with that answer is that it's not technically correct.

You're supposed to bury a *goldfish* for the desired result, and I believe the OP happened upon the solution because the cat had previously consumed a goldfish (not sure if they even knew that).

It's a good example of someone finding the right solution simply by luck, IMHO - no harm in keeping it around.

Comment: People just don't get their rituals straight these days... Everyone knows the cat is meant to be swallowed to catch the bird that was swallowed to catch the spider that was swallowed to catch the fly... *sighs*

Answer (score -19):

Humor is funny, humor is good. You are allowed to vote it up.

Don't be like the psychopaths of the SO.

Only laugh, vote it up and go away.